# Matrix exponential equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. Can one determine all the matrix $N\in\mathcal M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $e^N=M$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

Note that

$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \tag 1$

is singular; indeed,

$\det M = 0; \tag 2$

thus $M$ is not invertible; but any matrix of the form $e^N$ is always possessed of an inverse; in fact,

$e^N e^{-N} = e^{-N} e^N = e^{-N + N} = e^0 = I; \tag3$

that is, the inverse of $e^N$ is $e^{-N}$>

Comment: I think you mean "In a word, none". One *can* determine all such matrices, so the answer to the OP question is "yes".